# How do I store the data of a linked record in access at the time of a query

Tags: ms-access, record

I have an access database, it stores information on employee scores, these have the month that they occurred associated with them. I had been handed down this database and I am trying to fix an issue I am now running into. What is happening is, I have these records of the employee scores, they are linked to other tables with the employee's information such as their role, their manager, etc. when the employee information updates though it is impacting historical information. For example if Jimmy took a call in may and reported to John at the time. Later on Jimmy moves from John's team to Lisa's. If I pull the report it will show that Jimmy has always reported to Lisa, and his scores will impact the reports I am pulling on historical data. Is there a way to take a snapshot of the linked connection at the time I import the data so that the historical data will show they reported to John and current will show they report to Lisa?

Comment: If you don't want historical data to change then you need to save that data. You need a table that saves these team assignments. Each assignment would be a record, not just change a field value when Jimmy switched teams. Then either save this assignment record ID to whatever table stores Jimmy's 'call' event or associate records based on dates which can get tricky. Your question really is too broad and responses would basically be opinions on approach to use. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: So that other information is in other tables. I have tables for the data itself, the employees, the managers etc. I guess I am trying to figure out when I do the append query how do I save a copy of the current value in these linked fields so that further updates do not change them? I know how to append with the linked value but like I described it changes the historical data too. Ideally I want to have the employees and managers reflect current state and whenever I do the append query add that relevant data to the record so I can pull historical reports

Comment: The part I don't know how to do is save the current assignment of each employee's manager to the record without just saving the linked data itself. I don't know how to get just the current value is what I am really asking I guess

Comment: Your question is not really appropriate for Stackoverflow as it is too broad, there is no code for analysis, responses would be opinions, and there really isn't enough information to understand your data and business process. "So that other information is in other tables." - apparently not in line with what I suggested.

Comment: If you don't want to use a table for history of assignments, then saving the current assignment info into the 'calls' table means pulling data from Jimmy's record and populate fields in 'calls' table. This is duplicating data instead of relating records. More than one way to accomplish but all will most likely involve VBA. The real trick is figuring out what event to put code in.